# can't get Angular ui-grid last row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

is there a way to apply a specific template only to the last ui-grid 's row?
I triyed doing that using `<div ng-show="grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)==gridOptions.data.length-1">` but it seems not to be working :(
Am I missing something?
if I just replace `gridOptions.data.length-1` by a number it works correctly
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DXbOOgOyQdDwhQPHBSQG?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

```
cellTemplate:'<div ng-show="row.rowIndex==$scope.gridApi.grid.options.totalItems"><button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.showMe()">Click Me</button></div>' }
```